# What's the function of this cursor?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

When I use the direct selection tool to adjust my mesh anchor point while I pressing the alt key, the mouse cursor transformed into an icon with a small triangle at the right bottom of the cursor. what's the function of this new cursor? thank you.

Comment: If you try it and see, you will soon find out what it does.

Comment: ^ I think I saw this in a fortune cookie ;)

Comment: I can't find any methods.

Answer (score 2):

This cursor shows up when there's an object below another object. <kbd>Command</kbd> + click while this cursor is active will allow you to select the object below and cycle through the foreground and background objects on every click thereafter.

> **Select behind objects**
>
> In Illustrator, you can select objects that lie underneath other
>   objects using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click (Windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd>+click (Mac OS). The
>   pointer changes to Select Behind on the first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click (Windows) or
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>+click (Mac OS). On subsequent usage of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click (Windows) or
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>+click (Mac OS), the selection iterates through the objects
>   directly underneath the pointer position.
>
> *Source: [How to make selections in Illustrator: Select Behind Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-objects.html#select_behind_objects)*

Comment: it does not work sometimes, there must have something you left to say.